# Decode and filter local JSON with dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have a json file like below, there are about 16,000 records inside and the key part consists of dynamic keys (strings)

```
{"ABDULLAH GÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ (KAYSERİ)":[{"VAKIF": "DEVLET","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ABDULLAH GÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KAYSERİ","BÖLÜM": "Bilgisayar Mühendisliği"},{"VAKIF": "DEVLET","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ABDULLAH GÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KAYSERİ","BÖLÜM":"Biyomühendislik"},{"VAKIF": "DEVLET","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ABDULLAH GÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KAYSERİ","BÖLÜM": "Ekonomi"}],"ACIBADEM MEHMET ALİ AYDINLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ (VAKIF/İSTANBUL)":[{"VAKIF": "VAKIF","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ACIBADEM MEHMET ALİ AYDINLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "İSTANBUL","BÖLÜM": "Beslenme ve Diyetetik"},{"VAKIF": "VAKIF","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ACIBADEM MEHMET ALİ AYDINLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "İSTANBUL","BÖLÜM": "Beslenme ve Diyetetik"},{"VAKIF": "VAKIF","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ACIBADEM MEHMET ALİ AYDINLAR ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "İSTANBUL","BÖLÜM": "Beslenme ve Diyetetik"}],"ADA KENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ (VAKIF/KIBRIS)":[{"VAKIF": "KIBRIS","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ADA KENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KKTC","BÖLÜM": "Diş Hekimliği Fakültesi"},{"VAKIF": "KIBRIS","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ADA KENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KKTC-GAZİMAĞUSA","BÖLÜM": "Diş Hekimliği Fakültesi"},{"VAKIF": "KIBRIS","ÜNİVERSİTE": "ADA KENT ÜNİVERSİTESİ","ŞEHİR": "KKTC","BÖLÜM": "Diş Hekimliği Fakültesi"}]
```

and I have a struct like below;

```
    struct Bolum4: Codable {
    
    let vakif: String?
    let universite: String?
    let sehir: String?
    let bolum: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case vakif = "VAKIF"
        case universite = "ÜNİVERSİTE"
        case sehir = "ŞEHİR"
    case bolum = "BÖLÜM"
    }
}
```

and I am trying to decode this json with the function below;

```
   if let unv4json = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "unv4", withExtension: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: unv4json)
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

          let result = try jsonDecoder.decode([String:[Bolum4]].self, from:data)

            self.bolum4 = result

        } catch {
           // print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

But it takes all of the recordings in 3-4 seconds on the simulator and 10 seconds on the phone. is this time normal? If it is normal, I will either take it at the beginning of the application or take it in the background. Is there any way to get this in less time if it's not normal?

In addition, when decoding from json, is there a way not to get all of the recordings? for example; get the records like UNIVERSITY = “ADA KENT UNIVERSITY”. Thank you.

Comment: Decode the JSON **once** on the first launch of the app and put in Core Data. Then you can filter the records fast and efficiently.

Comment: It is a logical method that can be implemented and I added this to the options. thank you vadian.

Comment: @mehmeet43 You could move the entire data fetching and decoding to the background queue.

Comment: hi @frankenstein, thanks for your tip, i will try this method also.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the data fetching to the background thread and then come back to the main thread when the fetching would be complete. Here's the entire process:

```
func fetchBolum(completion: @escaping (Result<[String: [Bolum4]], Error>) -> Void) {
    if let unv4json = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "unv4", withExtension: "json") {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: unv4json)
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [Bolum4]].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success(result))
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fetchBolum { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let bolum):
        print(bolum)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

excep storing values once to core data, this article is also offer a clever solution; https://swiftsenpai.com/swift/decode-dynamic-keys-json/